# boot time start up code on Raspberry pi 3 jessie by adding script under init.d

Tags: pi-3, boot, script, jessie-lite, init.d

to run a script at start-up on my Raspberry pi 3 board ( with  jessie lite ) :

1- I added one init script under /etc/init.d/ directory. I can start,stop,restart service using script manually.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: LCD
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Liquid Crystal Display
# Description: date / time / ip address
### END INIT INFO


#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/lcd


export HOME
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting LCD"
       /root/Ccodes/charlcd &
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping LCD"
    killall charlcd
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lcd {start|stop}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

2-i made the script executable:

```
"sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/lcd"
```

3-an then Register script to be run at start-up

```
sudo update-rc.d lcd defaults
```

the script does not start on boot.

any suggestions?

by the way i can sucsessfully run it at boot using RC.LOCAL
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) used on Raspbian wheezy, which is "SysV-style", was replaced in jessie with **[systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)**.  This no longer uses `inittab` or `/etc/init.d`.

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

https://learn.adafruit.com/running-programs-automatically-on-your-tiny-computer/systemd-writing-and-enabling-a-service

Systemd is widely used beyond the Raspberry Pi and you will also find many general linux based resources around, including those linked at the bottom of the systemd homepage.

Comment: AFAIK systemd runs legacy init.d scripts just fine. Have you tried `systemctl enable lcd` and `systemctl start lcd`?

Comment: yep, but it didnot work!