# Running a program on boot (Pi 4)

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, script

I have been trying to get a program to start automatically on boot. I have tried using `systemd`, `init.d`, `rc.local`, and `cron` to execute my bash script in order to invoke a program (e.g. open an instance of LXTerminal), and still can’t see it on boot.

**systemd**: I created a service in `/etc/systemd/system/`, following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) template:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u main.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/myscript
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then created my bash script in `/etc/systemd/system` and made it executable, before following the instructions in the official Raspberry Pi documentation, running the following commands:

```
sudo cp myscript.service /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service
sudo systemctl start myscript.service
sudo systemctl stop myscript.service
sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
```

I was informed that a symlink was indeed created, but the program did not run after starting the service.

**init.d**: Following [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64363/boot-time-start-up-code-on-raspberry-pi-3-jessie-by-adding-script-under-init-d) example, I added one init script under /etc/initd/, made the script executable, and registered the script to be run at startup, with no result.

**rc.local**: Following the official documenation found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md), I added my bash script to the the rc.local file in `/etc/`, with no result.

**cron**: Following the official documentation found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md), I ran crontab with the `-e` flag to edit the cron table:

`crontab -e`

Then, I added a scheduled task to `crontab`:

`@reboot bash /home/pi/mybashscript.sh &`

Unfortunately, there was still no result.
I am hoping to use any method to run a program automatically on startup on Raspbian Buster. Please respond if you have had any experience with accomplishing this, or have ran into the same problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens when you run your `crontab` command from the CLI?

Comment: *I then created my bash script in /etc/systemd/system* why? what does the bash script do? how is it at all related to the service you created?

Comment: This Question is lacking the vital piece of evidence - viz. the script!

Comment: @Seamus, crontab hangs with no result, and the only choice seems to be to use a Control+C keyboard interrupt to exit out.

Comment: @JaromandaX, the bash script was to run my program with several parameters, but I got it working by adding "lxterminal -e bash /home/pi/myScript.sh" to my lxsession-autostart, as per Botspot's suggestion. My service's only purpose was to automatically start the script on boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> execute my bash script in order to invoke a program (e.g. open an instance of LXTerminal

If your auto-started program needs anything graphical, then you're trying the wrong thing.
Try putting it in the lxsession-autostart:

```
sudo mousepad /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add your command to the bottom of the file, then save and exit.

Comment: This works, thank you!  I was able to get it to autostart by adding  "lxterminal -e bash /home/pi/myScript.sh" to the lxsession autostart file, in order to have my script run in the LXTerminal terminal emulator.